# Редактирование изображений на основе opencv

Tags: python, алгоритм, opencv

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Возникла потребность создать алгоритм ,который сможешь преобразовать структурную схему резервирования. Пока только на примитивном уровне. Пример,на вход идёт фотография с схемой ,а алгоритм должен распознать где именно находятся эти прямоугольники,а затем заменить их (несколько параллельных - на один ,стерев старые и присвоив новое название,последовательные - сложить в один,и провернуть то же самое,как с параллельными). Планировал это все реализовать на opencv,но поиски ро интернету не дали никакой информации. Если ли какие-то методы у opencv,чтобы решить мою задачу? Либо возможно понадобится другая библиотека

Answer (score 0):

Есть слона нужно по частям.

Для начала освойте выделение контуров (findContours) и отрезков с помощью преобразования Хафа HoughLines.

Однако вначале придётся подготовить изображения - убрать неравномерность фона, шум, выровнять, вероятно - убрать перспективные искажения, бинаризовать и т.

---

После появления картинки  - нет, в OpenCV алгоритмов решения этой задачи нет, не для того она предназначена. [Вот что есть](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/)

Comment: А как дальше развивать алгоритм ? Не уверен,что определение контуров /отрезков тут основная задача

Comment: Ничего не могу сказать - задача пока слишком абстрактная. Несколько близких параллельных можно вычислить и обернуть описывающим прямоугольником boundingRect